# How to put designated value to textbox from drop down that in a loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How can I put a designated value to every textbox from drop down that has been loop?

Here's my PHP code:

```
<?php
while($rowb=mysql_fetch_array($b1)) 
 {
?>
        <input type="text" id="friendName">
   <select name="select[]" id="select" onchange="ChooseContact(this)"/>

<?php
   while($qrow=mysql_fetch_array($q1)) 
{
     <option value="<?php echo $qrow['type'];?>"><?php echo $qrow['type'];?></option>
<?php
   }
}  
?>
```

Javascript:

```
function ChooseContact(data) {    
  document.getElementById ("friendName").value = data.value;    
}
```

ok i have edited the code for much more clearer sorry for the first one.

Example output for this is that lets say i call it to loop for 2 times. The option value of the drop down menu are "a" and "b". So their will be 2 drop down menus and 2 input boxes. when I select a value from the first drop down lets say "a" then the first input box value be also "a". But when I choose lets say "b" on the 2nd drop down menu the value of the 2nd input box should be "b" but it appears blank and the value of the first input box that is "a" changes to "b". I expected "b" should appear to the 2nd input box but I cant figure out how to do that..

PLEASE HELP TNX!!

Comment: I'm assuming you edited the code to try and make it visible.  For reference, you can indent it by 4 spaces to have it show up verbatim.  If you could make it match the code you actually have, that'd help.

Comment: sorry for the first one, this is my first time to post to this site

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
while($rowb=mysql_fetch_array($b1))
{
?>
   <input type="text" id="friendName">

   <select name="select[]" id="select" onchange="ChooseContact(this)" >

<?php
   while($qrow=mysql_fetch_array($q1))
   {
?>
     <option value="<?php echo $qrow['type']; ?>"><?php echo $qrow['type']; ?></option}
<?php
   }
?>
</select>
<?php
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($rowb=mysql_fetch_array($b1))
{
?>
   <input type="text" id="friendName">

   <select name="select[]" id="select" onchange="ChooseContact(this)">
<?
   while($qrow=mysql_fetch_array($q1))
   {
?>
     <option value="<?echo $qrow['type'];?>"><? echo $qrow['type'] ?> </option>
<?
   }
}
```

Edit:

I think you should change `<input type="text" id="friendName">` to `<input type="text" name="friendName[]">`
and then change function to something like

```
function ChooseContact(data)
{ 
var x = document.getElementsByName("friendName[]");
for (i=1; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].value = data.value ;
 }
 }
```

Comment: I have Edited my post tnx need help